# How to avoid data loss in HighlevelProducer rdkafka

Tags: node.js, kafka-producer-api, confluent-platform, librdkafka, node-kafka

Using npm librdkafka i am producing large volume of data to the Kafka. I am using HighlevelProducer.
For 50K messages this configuration is working fine. But for larger volume like 100K messages, there is data loss. Data loss is varying from 200-1K based on configurations. Tried various configurations but unable to find best configuration to achieve 100% accuracy. any suggestions are helpful.
Below is my configuration.

```
var producerConfigOptions = {
            'request.required.acks': requireAcknowledge,
            'client.id': producerClientId,
            'compression.codec': 'gzip',
            'metadata.broker.list': msgSystemConnectionString,
            'security.protocol': 'ssl',
            'ssl.key.location': clintCertKeyFile,
            'ssl.certificate.location': clientCertFile,
            'ssl.ca.location': caFile,
            'retry.backoff.ms': 200,
            'message.send.max.retries': 10,
            'socket.keepalive.enable': true,
            'queue.buffering.max.messages': 50000,
            'queue.buffering.max.ms': 100,
            'batch.num.messages': 50000,
            'dr_cb': true,
            }

       var ProducerInstance= new Kafka.HighLevelProducer(producerConfigOptions);
        ProducerInstance.connect({}, (err) => {
        if(err)
        {
        console.log(error)
        }
        else
        {
        
            ProducerInstance.produce(topicName, lastUsedPartition, Buffer.from(msg), msgKey, Date.now(), (err, offset) => {
    //logic to store offset
        }
        
        }
        }
```

Comment: What's requireAcknowledge set to?  What's the replication-factor on your topics?

Comment: requireAcknowledge  is set to -1 and replication factor is 3. Tried with requireAcknowledge  as 1 but there is no difference

Comment: Use request.required.acks=-1 (all). Also make sure that you flush() your producer before terminating.